# CSS display:inline/none with tables works with Firefox but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: css, cross-browser, html-table

I am working on a quick and dirty application which involves several single-column tables displayed horizontally within an outer table.

```
|-------------------------------------------|
|             outer table                   |
|-------------------------------------------|
|    ---------    ---------    ---------    |
|    | table 1|   |table 2|    |table 3|    |
|    ---------    ---------    ---------    |
|    | row 1  |   | row 1 |    | row 1 |    |
|    ---------    ---------    ---------    |
|    ...                                    |
|    ---------    ---------    ---------    |
|    | row n  |   | row n |    | row n |    |
|    ---------    ---------    ---------    |
|                                           |
|-------------------------------------------|

        ---------    ---------    
        |SHOW #2|    |SHOW #3|
        ---------    ---------
```

I realize this could be done using css without tables, but I am not adept enough and this doesn't need to be elegant. At the start, only the first table is displayed.  Clicking buttons toggles the display from "none" to "inline" (I also tried "block") of #2 and #3.  In this example, I set the style of #2 in a DIV around the table and in #3 within a TD around the table.  Both methods work in Firefox 22.0 but not in Chrome 27.0 or Safari 5.0 (all on Mac).  Is there any solution using tables?  Or, if you'd like to design the style sheet, that works too :-)

```
<html>
<body>

<table id = "main" border=0 cellspacing=20>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id = "tbl1" border=0> 
                <tr><td> table #1, row #1 </td></tr>
                <tr><td> table #1, row #2 </td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td>
            <!-- Hide the table with a hidden DIV -->

            <div id = "tbl2" style="display:none">
              <table border=0>
                <tr><td> table #2, row #1 </td></tr>
                <tr><td> table #2, row #2 </td></tr>
            </table>
           </div>
       </td>

       <!-- Hide the table with a hidden TD -->

       <td id = "tbl3" style="display:none">
          <table border=0>
            <tr><td> table #3, row #1 </td></tr>
            <tr><td> table #3, row #2 </td></tr>
        </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table> 

<br>

<input type=button value ='show table #2' onclick='document.getElementById("tbl2").style="display:inline"'>
<input type=button value ='show table #3' onclick='document.getElementById("tbl3").style="display:inline"'>
<br>
<br>
<input type=button value ='hide table #2' onclick='document.getElementById("tbl2").style="display:none"'>
<input type=button value ='hide table #3' onclick='document.getElementById("tbl3").style="display:none"'>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `style="display: table-cell;"` worked in all browsers here (Windows).

Comment: made simple example http://jsfiddle.net/insanebits/beCML/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/etNrv/). While making it, I didn't know you did not want to use jQuery, but I strongly recommend you to change your mind, since all you have to do is adding this to your html, preferably just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input').on("click", function () {
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      var index = inputValue.indexOf("#")
      var divId = "#tbl" + inputValue.substr(index+1);
      $(divId).toggle();
  }); 
});
</script>
```

I also changed the html a bit: I'm using 1 input per table: **"show or hide"** in 1 button.
But you can ofcourse use 2 buttons for it: just change the jQuery and call hide() or show() accordingly. If you really don't wanna use jQuery, you could convert my example to pure JavaScript, but it seems like that's gonna take a bit more coding for you :)

Comment: Huh. I didn't realize that you could link directly to code.jQuery.com.  This makes the management of the app easier. So I will take your recommendation and go the jQuery route.  Thanks for the pithy code!

Comment: @LKramer Better use the one hosted on Google's CDN, not from the jQuery site. Link example would be `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`See https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: @pallandt Good point, especially after reading [this](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use TABS here and still have your table-Element.
Try this: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/
It should help you with your problem

Comment: Thanks, Paul, but I need all the tables to show at once.  (I am also steering clear of jQuery for this app.)